# Hyper-v internet connection within the VM is veeeeery slow [Host is unaffected]

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v, network-adapter

I've been searching for the last couple of days for a solution for this issue.

I've found myriads for threads regarding the external/default switch and how they affect the HOST, with no connectivity, etc.

My problem is quite different - and tested on 2 machines in the same house.
The host is fine, the guest is the one with awful internet speed and only internet speed - the network speed is fine (100 MB/s+)

The scenario goes like this:
I create a new VM for Windows 10.
Everything is fine.
Windows 10 update seems unaffected.

First thing I do is download 7z - the downloader proceeds to download the file at around 24 KB/s and not going any higher (16 mbps here - around 2 MB/s)
So anyway this is a 1MB exe so I ignore it.
I copy over Visual Studio 2017 from my host and run it.
First thing it tries to update the installer.

The download is running at 2KB/s and not going any further.
No amount of settings and configuration changes had a positive effect on this.

- So I tried default/external switch
- I disabled the VMQ setting I
- updated my NIC driver Played around with the Advanced NIC settings in
  the connection.
- Disabled firewall / 3rd party VPN on and off
- Disabled offloading

All that and there is no improvement what-so-ever

The host is fine and is downloading at normal speeds with no problem.

I am also running the latest version of windows:

```
Host: 1903 (18362)
2nd Host: 1809 (17763)
Guest: 1809 (17763)
```

When transferring over network from my host to guest the transfer speed is ok, around 100MB/s - only the internet is slow

Also one machine is wired and the other is wireless

Anything I am missing here?

[image: Screenshot]